# CSV file creation is shorter than expected

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I'm creating a CSV file, I'm using C# and CsvHelper to do so.

My CSV file ends up being 205 lines long each time. I know for certain that it should be creating 240 entries, which is what I want.

It seems to stop creating the CSV file at 205 lines. When running it several times it will produce the same result of 205 entry's. Interestingly the last field it attempts to write is one letter short and I'm not sure why.

Below is the full code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using CsvHelper;
using System.IO;

namespace PinGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GeneratePins generatePins = new GeneratePins();
            generatePins.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class GeneratePins
    {
        private Dictionary<string, String> pinNumbers = new Dictionary<string, String>();
        private List<String> duplicatePinCheck = new List<string>();
        private Random random = new Random();

        // Runs the sequence for the generation of TimeSpans & Pin Numbers.
        // Stores these into JSON / CSV Files
        public void Start()
        {            
            TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan();
            TimeSpan maxTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);

            TimeSpan currentTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            string currentPin = "0000";

            // CSV File Creation
            TextWriter textWriter = File.CreateText(@"pinNumber.csv");
            var csv = new CsvWriter(textWriter);

            while (timeSpan.Duration() < maxTime.Duration())
            {
                // Create TimeSpan & Pin
                timeSpan = timeSpan.Add(currentTimeSpan);
                currentPin = RandomNumber();

                // Duplicate Check
                while (duplicatePinCheck.Contains(currentPin))
                {
                    currentPin = RandomNumber();
                }
                duplicatePinCheck.Add(currentPin);

                // Cache Results
                string entryPinNumber = currentPin;
                string entryTimeSpan = timeSpan.ToString();

                // JSON
                pinNumbers.Add(entryTimeSpan, currentPin);

                // CSV Creation - Write to CSV File
                csv.WriteField(entryTimeSpan);
                csv.WriteField(entryPinNumber);
                csv.NextRecord();

                // CONSOLE
                Console.WriteLine(entryPinNumber + " / " + timeSpan.ToString());          
            }
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pinNumbers, Formatting.Indented);

            // Write to JSON File
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"pinNumbers.json"))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(file, pinNumbers);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Created " + pinNumbers.Count() + " pin numbers.");
        }

        public string RandomNumber()
        {
            String result = random.Next(0, 9999).ToString();
            result = result.PadLeft(4, '0');
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not edit in meta-commentary regarding downvotes into your question. Not only is it considered noise, I can *promise* you it will just lead to more downvotes. As far as constructive technical criticism goes, one problem I see is that you included your *full* code, rather than a [mcve]. Some people may consider that downvote-worthy, as it makes answering more work for them. Otherwise, this looks fairly reasonable to me. 2 downvotes really isn't a lot. That could just be explained by asking a question that experts do not find especially interesting.

Comment: Ok thanks Cody Gary. For the record I do much prefer giving smaller snippets of code, I'm happy to trim this down. Often I'll get asked to provide more, I guess its knowing what the balance is.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextWriter textWriter = File.CreateText(@"pinNumber.csv");
```

Needed to be changed to

```
StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText(@"pinNumber.csv");
```

Comment: As far as I can see the problem wasn't the `TextWriter`, but the fact that you neither call `.Dispose()' (which you should) nor '.Flush()' on any writer. You even said that the last value was one letter short. Of course it was, the rest was never flushed. The first part was probably only written because the internal buffer was completely filled.

Comment: Ah thank you Milster. I suppose that the reason it worked when changing it to StreamWriter is because it will handle internal buffer itself?

Comment: `StreamWriter` also has to be disposed (at which point it will flush all remaining content). I would assume you will have the same problem with it at some point. To be safe, wrap your writers in a using statement, because at the end of it, it will automatically be disposed and you can't forget to do it.